# Is it possible to train neural network to generate similar pictogram?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

Is it possible to give the neural network and pictogram and train him to generate variant of this picto?

I know there is some initiative to generate vectors drawings like https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/models/sketch_rnn/README.md or some logos generated by AI but it's not really qualitative…

Any idea/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most classes of generative models of images (with the notable exception of autoregressive models) have a "latent" space.

Typically, a property of a well trained and sufficiently powerful generative model is that traversing the latent space also smoothly traverses the image space in a coherent manner, yielding variants of the starting image.

So in short: train a generative model, then take nearby points in your latent space to obtain "variants"